# Error: Failed to run 'pdflatex' to create pdf to preview

Tags: sublime-text

```
Error: Failed to run 'pdflatex' to create pdf to preview
```

I keep getting this error in my build of sublime 3. To be clear, my files compile perfectly and I have no other problems with Latex but this. The problem is that sublime keeps putting this error inline right below where I am typing and it is very distracting. It is causing no other problems, it is just distracting. It only seems to show up when I enter mathmode, whenever I type $$ and write something in here $$ it gives me that error.

Does anyone know how to disable preview or how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sorry, but the information you give is insufficient to make a diagnosis.

Comment: Thats a new LaTeXTools feature to preview math equations, while editing. You can disable the feature by setting [preview_math_mode](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/v3.12.5/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings#L100) to "none" or try to debug it with the information of [#883](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/883). We are still at the process of handling error cases and open to suggestions.

Comment: @r-stein Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a new LaTeXTools feature to preview math equations, while editing. You can disable the feature by setting [preview_math_mode](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/v3.12.6/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings#L100) to `"none"` or try to debug it.

Most likely you are missing one of the following packages: standalone, preview, latexsym, or mathtools.
In version `3.12.6` there should be two button added to that phantom. Click *(Check System)* to run a system check, which will also search for the required packages. If the system check does not show any problem click on *(Show Report)* to see a report about the failure. This should contain the build errors and help you to fix that problem.

Answer (score 11):

When you see this error, you should be able to see a link/button called "show report", so:

1. Click this link, which will open a new page with detailed log.
2. In this page you will find a copy of the mini LaTeX document used for compilation. This should include some head definitions, and the main content is nothing but **your equation**. Shown below:
   [image: LaTeX used for compilation]
3. Copy this mini LaTeX document to a new file, save and compile it, just like a normal LaTeX document.
4. MiKTeX should report some missing packages, you can let MiKTeX install them automatically or install them yourself.
   [image: MiKTeX prompt]
5. Go back to your main document, now it should work.
   For example:
   [image: Working math preview]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What has this to do with the Sublime issue mentioned here?

Comment: Well, this is exactly what people see in sublime text (for the mentioned problem ), and what you can do to solve it.  The "Check System" button as mentioned by r-stein currently performs an incomplete check, so not all missing packages can be identified. The only way is to compile the mini latex sample once.

Comment: This worked for me! @HaoLiu is right, "Check System" is not sufficient. Furthermore, this solution automatically finds the missing packages and prompts to install them - no manual package installation required. Thanks.